# For simple $R$-modules, $A$,$B$, and $C$ if $A\oplus C\cong B\oplus C$ as $R$-modules then $A\cong B$ as $R$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm supposing that there exists some $R$-module isomorphism $\varphi:A\oplus C\to B\oplus C$ and considering the following inclusion and projection maps:
$$\iota:A\to A\oplus C$$ and $$\pi:B\oplus C\to B,$$ which are both $R$-module homomorphisms. It follows that $F:=(\pi\circ \varphi)\circ\iota\in \text{Hom}_R(A,B)$. By Schur's Lemma, $F$ is either $0$ or an isomorphism.

Suppose we have $F(a)=0$ for all $a\in A$. $$\pi(\varphi(\iota(a)))=\pi(\varphi((a,0_C)))=0 \implies \varphi((a,0_C))=(0,c)$$ for some $c\in C$. As $a$ was arbitrary, $$\varphi(A\oplus \{0\})\subseteq \{0\}\oplus C\cong C.$$ $C$ is simple $\implies$ $\varphi(A\oplus \{0\})=\{0\}$ or $C$. As $\varphi$ is an isomorphism we must have $\varphi(A)=C$ .

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways you can do this.

**Method 1**

Consider these compositions

$$f:A\to A\oplus C\cong B\oplus C\to B$$
$$g:A\to A\oplus C\cong B\oplus C\to C$$
$$h:C\to A\oplus C\cong B\oplus C\to B$$

Each of them is zero or an isomorphism by Schur's lemma. If $f$ is an isomorphism we are done. If not then $f=0$. In this case $g$ is an isomorphism. Then $h$ cannot be $0$, otherwise all of $A\oplus C$ goes to the $C$ component of $B\oplus C$ under the isomorphism, which is absurd. Hence $h$ is an isomorphism, and $hg:A\cong B$.

**Method 2**

Consider the composition series
$$A\oplus C\supset C\supset0$$
$$B\oplus C\supset C\supset0$$
and conclude with the Jordan-Holder theorem.

**Method 3**

Note that simple modules are indecomposable and that the direct sum of two simple modules is Noetherian and Artinian. Use the Krull-Remak-Schmidt theorem.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify why $f=0 \implies g$ is an isomorphism? I can see if $h=0$ then similarly to what I showed above we would have $\varphi(A\oplus C)\subseteq \{0\}\oplus C\cong C \implies \varphi(A\oplus C)=C$.

Comment: @shamcallado Otherwise both $f,g$ are zero, which implies the image of $A\oplus\{0\}$ in $B\oplus C$ under the isomorphism is zero. But $A$ is simple and thus by definition nonzero. It cannot be sent to zero by any isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for $\phi$ to be an isomorphism while $F = 0$. Take $A = B = C$ and let $\phi: A \oplus A \longrightarrow A \oplus A$ be the twist isomorphism, i.e. $(a_1, a_2) \mapsto (a_2, a_1)$. Then let $\iota: A \longrightarrow A \oplus A$ via $a \mapsto (a, 0)$ and $\pi: A \oplus A \longrightarrow A$ via $(a_1, a_2) \mapsto a_1$. These are the inclusion to and projection onto the first coordinate, as in your definition. Then $F = \pi \circ \phi \circ \iota: A \longrightarrow A$ takes $a \mapsto (a, 0) \mapsto (0, a) \mapsto 0$, so $F = 0$ despite $\phi$ being an isomorphism.

Comment: So maybe instead of reaching a contradiction, we can just see that the zero map results in this trivial case of $A=B=C$.

Comment: I think my answer shows that the map $F$ you define won't work in general. Similarly to the edit you made, whenever $\phi[A] \subseteq C$ you run into the same issue. I'm not sure how to solve this problem, but this map has many cases where it doesn't work so you'll likely want to look elsewhere.